# save UIImage to disk with simulator ios 8 doesn't work

Tags: objective-c, file, ios8

the following code works great on ios < 8 but **doesn't work** with xcode 6.1.1 and ios 8 device simulator

```
NSData *imageData = UIImagePNGRepresentation(shareSnapshot);
[imageData writeToFile:@"/Users/MyUser/Desktop/123.png" atomically:YES];
```

Does anyone know if this is a simulator issue I don't have a real device with ios8 to check on.

Comment: You don't have a real disk path.

Answer (score 0):

So you're running into a permission issue here. I'm not sure *why* it worked before 8.0, but I'm seeing (something clearly changed):

> The operation couldn't be completed. (Cocoa error 513)

https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/ErrorHandlingCocoa/ErrorObjectsDomains/ErrorObjectsDomains.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40001806-CH202-CJBGAIBJ

As it stands, you'll run into problems when running it on an actual device. The better way to handle this is to save data to your application's document directory.

1. Fetch the directory path via NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES)
2. Append the filename using stringByAppendingPathComponent

You can then verify that it's saving properly by visiting the simulators application directory:

- /Users/user/Library/Developer/CoreSimulator/Devices//Documents/

Comment: I've tried that the results are the same, bellow IOS 8 works fine but not with IOS 8 and up

Comment: You most certainly have permission to write to the documents directory. You may want to build a small sample project that just does this. Feel free to push that sample to Github and I'd be happy to test it on this end.

Answer (score 0):

I remember you cannot give a path like "/Users/MyUser/Desktop/" for iOS due to security and sandbox reasons.

check out

`NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSCachesDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES);`

document to find a proper location

`NSSearchPathDirectory` defines a lot of paths you can use. Hope this help

Answer (score 0):

```
    UIGraphicsBeginImageContext(self.frame.size);
[self.layer renderInContext:UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext()];

    UIImage *image = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext();
UIGraphicsEndImageContext();

// Now I use the "screenshot"
NSString *path = [NSHomeDirectory() stringByAppendingString:@"/image.jpg"];
if ([UIImageJPEGRepresentation(image, 1) writeToFile:path atomically:YES]) {
    NSLog(@"save ok");
}
else {
    NSLog(@"save failed");
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try This.

Swift 3.0

```
// Create path.
let paths = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(.documentDirectory, .userDomainMask, true)
let filePath = "\(paths[0])/MyImageName.png"
// Save image.
UIImagePNGRepresentation(image)?.writeToFile(filePath, atomically: true)
```